# Two graphs with shared Vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

I am not sure wether this is the correct Stackexchange for the question. Please let me know if it isn't.

I am trying to solve the following problem and was wondering wether or not my solution is correct:

> Given two forests with a shared set of vertices: $(V,E_1),(V,E_2)$ and $|E_1|<|E_2|$. Show that you can find an edge $e \in E_2\setminus E_1$ such that $(V,E_1 \cup \{e\})$ is a forest as well.

**My attempt**:

1. I know that a forest with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges and $p$ connected components satisfies $n = p + m$. Applying this to our case, we obtain: $p_1 + m_1 = p_2 + m_2 \implies p_1 > p_2, \quad (m_i = |E_i|)$. Therefore, $(V,E_1)$ has strictly more connected components.
2. We define $G_u := (V, E_1 \cup (E_2 \setminus E_1))$. Also, notice that $(V,E_2 \setminus E_1)$ is a forest.
3. $G_u$ has less connected components than both $(V,E_i)$, because of 1 and 2..

Combining points 1. and 3., there must be a path in $G_u$ connecting two vertices of unconnected parts of $(V,E_1)$. Taking the edge $\{ e \}$ where the connection happens, we connect two trees and thus obtain a new forest $(V,E_1 \cup e)$.

**If this doesn't work**, here are a few things that i thought I might use:

1. If there is no circle in $G_u$, then any edge of $E_2\setminus E_1$ will do the job and we are done. So we can assume that there is a circle.
2. Consider a circle in $G_u$, then there must be at least two vertices of mixed neighbourhoods ($\delta(v_i) \cap E_1 \neq \emptyset \neq \delta(v_i) \cap E_2\setminus E_1$), because you can go from $v_1$ to $v_2$ both in $(V,E_1)$ and in $(V,E_2 \setminus E_1)$, thus making a circle ($(V,E_i)$ are circlefree).

Related:

- [Forest graphs $F_1$ and $F_2$ with same vertices but different edges. Prove there is an edge where $F_1$ with it is still a forest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401954/forest-graphs-f-1-and-f-2-with-same-vertices-but-different-edges-prove-ther?rq=1)

Comment: Your idea is correct. You should formalize what unconnected and the edge where the connection happens means.